# Move and resize link based on page size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, annotations

I have a webpage that sets the background to an image, for example, a contents page. Along with this, there are invisible link overlays which sit on top so if the user presses on the correct area, the link is activated.

If the page loads the background in a smaller resolution, the links obviously do not change, but I cannot seem to work out a formula to resize and move the overlay back to the correct place.

The original size of the page is 1299px by 1794px

The new size is 512px by 707px

and the css for the overlay is:

```
<section class="annotLink" style="border-width: 0px; width: 262.217px; 
    height: 342.867px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); left: 347.126px; top: 72.379px; 
    position: absolute; transform: matrix(2.181, 0, 0, 2.181, -78.516, -78.516); 
    transform-origin: -339.126px -44.379px 0px;">    
<div style="top: -4px; left: -4px; bottom: -4px; right: -4px;" 
     class="annotationHighlight" hidden="true"></div>    
<a class="internalLink" onclick="event.preventDefault(); JumpToPage(40)" 
     href="javascript:void(0);" title=""></a>    
</section>
```

Any help is appreciated, if you need any more information, just ask.

*EDIT*

They can be seen working here:

Original size:
http://adamdevarea.x10host.com/page-fits.html

New size:
http://adamdevarea.x10host.com/page-doesnt-fit.html

Comment: can you not use percentage based positioning? Without being able to see this it's very hard for anyone to help with the limited code provided

Comment: Sorry. Ive edited the original post and added links to view both pages. I have tried some maths to divide the position/size etc and using percentages but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely doable. It's hard to test with Firebug but I've managed to have the good ratio by adding `transform: scale(.83)!important` on `.annotLink`.

Tweak it a little more with some translate and you should have it !

You can even adjust those values on the fly with Javascript.

PS : this page will soon give you big headaches ... :) so many magic numbers ... Hi from France !

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried this but it's not dynamic, so if the size of the page/image changes, that scale won't work.

My initial thought was to work out the ratio from the original size which I will always know, to the new size using jQuery, then applying the ratio to the styles. It was close but not perfect.